# SQL condition on only 1 column

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I'm struggling to find how I can put a where condition in only 1 column.

To sum up I want to have a column of all tickets in the database and another column of all ticket with a given date.

My SQl request :

```
SELECT
  i.created AS creation, l.label AS activite, 
  COUNT(l.label) AS nbTicket, COUNT(l.label) AS nbEntree
FROM label AS l INNER JOIN
     jiraissue AS i
     ON (l.issue = i.id) AND i.issuetype <> 3
GROUP BY activite
```

So up here I have all tickets from the database but if I had the where condition with the date :

```
SELECT l.label AS activite, SUM(i.timespent/3600/8) AS consomme, SUM(i.timeestimate/3600/8) AS raf, COUNT(l.label) AS nbTicket, 
    SUM(i.timeoriginalestimate/3600/8) AS chargeProvisoire, COUNT(l.label) AS nbEntree 
    FROM label AS l INNER JOIN jiraissue AS i ON (l.issue = i.id)  
    WHERE l.label IN ('Devis','TGC1','TGC2','TGC3','TGC4','TGC5','TGC5-Bis','TGC6','TGC7','TGC8','TGC8-Bis','TGC9','TGC10','TGC10-Bis','TGC12','TGC13','TGC13-Bis','TGC14','TGC50','TGC60')
    AND i.issuetype <> 3 AND i.created LIKE "2014-01-%" GROUP BY activite
```

I have only the ticket of January 2019.

Is their a solution to have all tickets in the column ==> nbTicket and all the ticket with the 'where' clause in the column ==> nbEntree ?

Comment: `i.created AS creation` can contain invalid (unmatching) data, because it seams you are using [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) in a invalid way

Comment: yes i see that but the request work i just delete information because it was too long

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: i edited my sql

Comment: @EMIN3M "the request works" -- You mean MySQL accepts it and it doesn't crash. Right. The problem is MySQL is giving you **random** rows. Use an aggregation function always, on columns not present in the `GROUP BY` as @RaymondNijland says.

Comment: *" Use an aggregation function always, on columns not present in the GROUP BY as @RaymondNijland says. "* Well @TheImpaler SQL:1999 and later standards permits such nonaggregates per optional feature if they are [functionally dependent](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html)  which MySQL also supports .. So basiclly that means queries like `SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY id` or `SELECT *, MIN(column) FROM table GROUP BY id`   can be valid SQL if the id column is primary or unique key.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Wow, that's a feature I didn't know about SQL:1999. To my point, though, MySQL does not enforce this dependency, and allows non-functionally dependent columns to show non-aggregated (selecting one random row). As a general rule I think it's better to avoid this SQL feature in MySQL.

Comment: The modern MySQL versions ~5.7+ should handle it correctly @TheImpaler *"MySQL implements detection of functional dependence. If the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default), MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them. "* it in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) ..

Comment: .. You indeed need to be carefull which using MySQL 5.6 versions or less then your beter off using the "full" `GROUP BY` standards because there there is no functional dependence detection and or a error.. Meaning you can get invalid data.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks. This opened a good discussion. To find out why I was so against this feature, I just tested it on MySQL 5.5, MySQL 8.0, MariaDB 10.0 and MariaDB 10.3 (latest). From my local tests, it's only safe in MySQL 8.0. I guess MySQL has an edge on this point compared to MariaDB.

Comment: @TheImpaler *"it's only safe in MySQL 8."* it should be save to use from MySQL  5.7.5+ and up that is it what the MySQL 5.7 [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) is mentioning.. *"I guess MySQL has an edge on this point compared to MariaDB"* indeed there seams to be a feature [request](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11588) so it might get implementated in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a conditional `SUM()` in the first query, as in:

```
SELECT
  max(i.created) AS creation,
  l.label AS activite, 
  COUNT(*) AS nbTicket,
  SUM(case when i.created LIKE "2019-01-%" then 1 end) AS nbEntree
FROM label AS l INNER JOIN
     jiraissue AS i
     ON (l.issue = i.id) AND i.issuetype <> 3
GROUP BY activite
```

Comment: Thanks i perfectly what i needed